# strstr does not work with variable from xml file

Tags: php, strstr

I have some problem with the function strstr in php.

```
 $text=file_get_contents("text.txt"); 
 echo $text.'<br><br>';
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('listmv.xml');
 foreach($xml->item as $item)
 {
$quoi="sangs rgyas";
if (strstr($text,$quoi)) { echo 'yes';}
 }
```

strstr retruns "yes",

```
 $text=file_get_contents("text.txt");
 echo $text.'<br><br>';
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('listmv.xml');
 foreach($xml->item as $item)
 {
$quoi=$item->tib;
if (strstr($text,$quoi)) { echo 'yes';}
 }
```

does not work.
What is the matter in this?

XML file:-

```
<list> 
  <item>
    <tib>sangs rgyas</tib>
    <ref>1524</ref>
  </item> 
  <item>
    <tib>rgya gar skad du</tib>
    <ref>1522</ref>
  </item> 
  <item>
    <tib>shes pa dang</tib>
    <ref>1523</ref>
  </item> 
  <item>
    <tib>'tsho ba dang</tib>
    <ref>1525</ref>
  </item> 
</list>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return an item from SimpleXML as in your loop...

```
foreach($xml->item as $item)
{
    $quoi=$item->tib;
    if (strstr($text,$quoi)) { echo 'yes';}
}
```

if you add

```
var_dump($quoi);
```

you will see it is actually a SimpleXMLElement and not a string...

```
class SimpleXMLElement#5 (1) {
  public ${0} =>
  string(11) "sangs rgyas"
}
```

Things like `echo` will cast it to a string, so use

```
if (strstr($text,(string)$quoi)) { echo 'yes';}
```

Comment: @NigelRen  `strstr('ab','b')  == false`

Answer (score 0):

It was returining a object you need to convert it to string.
Corrected code

```
 $text=file_get_contents("text.txt");
 echo $text.'<br><br>';
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('listmv.xml');
 foreach($xml->item as $item)
 {
$quoi=$item->tib;
if (strstr($text,$quoi->__toString())) { echo 'yes';}
 }
```